# heroku postgres sql changes not reflected in db

Tags: postgresql, python, heroku

I wrote this program

```
import psycopg2 


try:
    #connect to db

    cursor = connection.cursor()

except Exception as e:
    raise e
else:
    print("connection Success")
cmd = ""
while(True):
    cmd= input("Enter cmd")
    if cmd == "CLOSE":
        break
    try:

        cursor.execute(cmd)
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        print("Err")
        print(e)
        pass
    else:
        record = ""
        try: 
            record = cursor.fetchall()
        except Exception as e:

            print(e)


        print("Success ")
        print(record)

        pass
    finally:
        pass

cursor.close()
connection.close()
print("all close")
```

Weirdly, it worked fine yesterday for sometime. 
However now changes are not reflected in db (when checked through heroku dataclip) but can be seen through python app before closing the session.Only .
I an sure I haven't crossed any limit of the hobby dev plan.

Curious enough the primary key still increments.
Output example-
[image]

this query(insert into info(name,nickname,ismetro) values('abc', 'xyx','n') worked a while ago.

Comment: What is the cmd you are passing? Also you may want to review [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466741/parameterized-queries-with-psycopg2-python-db-api-and-postgresql) on parameterization.

Comment: sql statment eg:  select * from info

Comment: Since I will be entering query cmd is a string that is entered by the user from the terminal.Actually I should have added a picture.

Comment: since I am entering the string I think I am fine with queries as long as I dont use "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never committing your transaction. Add `connection.commit()` before you call `cursor.close()`. [Docs here](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html#connection.commit).

Comment: Thanks a lot, cant believe I missed this.

Comment: But still seldom an insert query used to work. Do you know why?